# getting error while using http post method flutter

Tags: http, flutter, http-headers

i am getting the success message as false while post the register api in flutter,first i am using the client url and get the token after thar i was pass the token to headers og register api.

```dart
Future<Register> fetchPost0() async {
  print('feg');
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  //String token = prefs.getString('token');

  String receivedToken = await _getMobileToken("BearerToken");

  receivedToken = "Bearer "+ receivedToken;

  print(receivedToken + "======================");


  Map  formData = {
    "firstname": "Dsemo",
    "lastname": "Usesr",
    "email": "sdfdsfsdf.asdf@vipmasdfil.hu",
    "password": "password",
    "confirm": "password",
    "address_1": "Demo",
    "country_id": "81",
    "postcode": "3333",
    "zone_id": "1256",
    "tax_id": "1",
    "customer_group_id": "1",
    "agree": "1"

  };


  final response = await http.post(
    'http://your api/register/register', body: json.encode(formData)
    ,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': receivedToken
      },
  );
  print(response.body);
  var   responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  print("Result: ${response.body}"); 
  return Register.fromJson(responseJson);
}
```

now i was edit the code it works fine.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: edit post body to - `body: json.encode(formData)`

Comment: I/flutter (10067): feg
I/flutter (10067): Bearer 3c2967524584b47e512bdb7b3e3928bbcc540173======================
I/flutter (10067): >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
I/flutter (10067): {"success":false}
I/flutter (10067): Result: {"success":false}
I/flutter (10067): Instance of 'Register'
After generating the barer token it shows success msg as false,
but while checking insomnia rest client it works fine